# WinSock connecting between two machines on different networks goes wrong C

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I made a server/client program, everything works fine when I make a connection on the same network or on the same machine. This is however my problem: when I disconnect the client machine from the local network and connect it to another network(wifi) it doesn't connect to the server.

This is a part of my server:

```
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        res = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &result);
```

Client:

```
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        res = getaddrinfo(SERVER_HOST, PORT, &hints, &result);
```

The destination port in my client code is the same port as the one in my server. I read somewhere that I have to buy a unique IP address? So my question is: **How can I connect two computers on different networks using sockets in C (WinSock)?**

Comment: The networks need to be able to access each other. You can try using `route` command from one to another. Or a simple ping for the address and port of the other side. If they are not reachable you need to set up a route using the system, or use DNS. And if they are in private networks using NAT you also may need to set up port forwarding. You can also use some kind of registration on a 3rd accessible address on services like [No-IP](https://www.noip.com/)

Comment: I searched up route but couldn’t find anything. So I have to change the host ip address of my server?

Comment: why search for route? It is a system command. In Windows or Linux or MacOS (Linux). If your system has no route for the other this is what will happen to your program. Try `help route` on Windows, `man route` on Linux an there you go

Comment: Hmm okay, can you give me some sources where I can learn more about this?

Comment: well, any intro book on networking will do. Short version: if both machines are inside private networks, like domestic routers, you need to set up routes on these devices, this is called port forwarding. Or you need to set up some way for these machines to register. You can use something like a VPN. Maybe as simple as Himachi, wich I believe is free

Comment: Okay thank you I’m gonna look intocut. Is it difficult?

Comment: I mispelled [Hamachi](http://vpn.net) . I did not understand your last comment :(

Comment: Hi, I figured out that I need port forwarding on my router in order to make my program accessible to other computers. But thank you for help!

Comment: I meant: into it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out that I need port forwarding on my router. Just contacted my network provider because I didn't had the option to make a new 'port forward rule'. I made a new rule in my router configuration. I put my private (internal) ip address into the new rule with a port number that I use in my server/client program. [This is a nice resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92b-jjBURkw&t=102s&ab_channel=HusseinNasser).

Comment: You can always try [Hamachi](https://vpn.net) or [openVPN](http://openvpn.net) or anything like them